# Mouse is blinking/flickering at my built in monitor with an external monitor, please help

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, mouse, flicker

I am using a Thinkpad W530, and due to my works, I need to use an external monitor.

I am using nouveau and nvidia-prime to switch between intel and nvidia adapter.

After I connected and switched on the external monitor (an Acer AL1716) my cursor start to be flickering/blinking at my built in monitor.

Whenever I switch off the external monitor, the cursor is nice again. I have read some questions about this issue, the solution is switch off the external monitor.

**However, I need to use external monitor**. Could anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to force fullscreen re-draws.

```
apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

There in section **Workarounds** check option **Force full screen redraws (buffer swap) on repaint**

Or, you can try these two:

**Fix screen updates in XGL with fglrx**

**Force syncronization between X and GLX**